# Registering your webapp is required for Google Data APIs use?

Tags: google-app-engine, gdata-api

I'm very new in appengine development and I'm trying to develop some tests apps that make use of Google Data API's.

I'm following this tutorial: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html#OAuthAuthorizeToken

- I have some test apps
  on my appspot account, but I can't
  register these webapps [as Google
  says](https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains), I need my own domain for
  use GData API's?
- Are, key and secret, parameters that
  Google give to me after webapp
  registration?

code:

```
String CONSUMER_KEY = "example.com";
String CONSUMER_SECRET = "abc123doremi";

GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
```

- What is a best practice to get these values, key and secret? I was following this tuto too, [Retreiving GData Feeds](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/java/retrieving_gdata_feeds.html), and I'm confusing about the Suggested enhancements

> This article slightly oversimplifies
>   the process for the sake of clarity:
>   in your own application, you would
>   likely **make use of the UserService in
>   both step1 and step2 to authenticate a
>   user**. Your application would persist
>   the request token. When a user
>   finished the step of authorizing your
>   application, you would fetch the
>   request token from the datastore,
>   upgrade it to an access token, then
>   persist the access token key/secret
>   pair in the datastore and associate it
>   with the logged in user. On subsequent
>   visits to your application by the
>   user, you would simply check for the
>   presence of an access token and
>   attempt to make API calls - the user
>   never has to go through the
>   authorization step again unless they
>   revoke your credentials or you delete
>   their access token from the datastore.
>   Describing these steps is slightly out
>   of the scope of this article, however,
>   they are a great set of "next steps"
>   for developers to guide themselves
>   towards mastering using OAuth and
>   GData with App Engine.

I'm using UserService in the manner is explained in [StockWatcher example](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/appengine.html#user), but I don't understand how to mix OAUTH with that.

Comment: You have your own domain that you can register with: yourapp.appspot.com.

Comment: Woah! That's true! I made ​​a mistake when typing the appspot domain >_<. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***a. I need my own domain for use GData API's?***

Registration is optional but recommended.
Web applications that [opt not to register](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html) with Google **can still use OAuth** using a lower level of security. In this case, Google does not automatically recognize the calling web application and adds a caution to the Google login page:

[image]

All calls requesting or using an OAuth token **must be signed**, regardless of whether your application is registered with Google or not.
If your application is not registered, [to sign the Request](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#SigningOAuth) you will use the following key and secret:

- consumer key: "anonymous"
- consumer secret: "anonymous"

***2. Are, key and secret, parameters that Google give to me after webapp registration?***

Yes, once you've [registered](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=162105&&hl=en), Google will provide you with a consumer key (and secret for use with HMAC-SHA1), and a place to upload a public certificate.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I found useful info here too: http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-oauth.html